# Writing on multiple shards in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Generally, if a query spreads across multiple shards, it is considered less optimized. It takes more time than reading from single shard.

Does it hold true for writing as well? If I am writing some data and it will distribute among multiple shards, will it be considered less optimized?

If yes, what is the best way to write a batch that should go to different shard?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operations, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#sharding-mongos-targeted.

> All insertOne() operations target to one shard. Each document in the insertMany() array targets to a single shard, but there is no guarantee all documents in the array insert into a single shard.
>
> All updateOne(), replaceOne() and deleteOne() operations must include the shard key or _id in the query document. MongoDB returns an error if these methods are used without the shard key or _id.
>
> Depending on the distribution of data in the cluster and the selectivity of the query, mongos may still perform a broadcast operation to fulfill these queries.